# cannot convert from 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label' to 'string'?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, gridview, label

I want to insert some values from grid to db while clicking button submit. While using the given below code shows an error. The code is given below. Help me to find a proper solution.

Code:

```
protected void btnApprove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        ShadingAnalysisDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_ItemRequest_StatusTableAdapter rs;
        rs = new ShadingAnalysisDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_ItemRequest_StatusTableAdapter();

        var ItemName = (Label)GridView2.SelectedRow.Cells[1].FindControl("lblItem");
        var Quantity = (Label)GridView2.SelectedRow.Cells[2].FindControl("lblQnty"); 

        rs.testInsert(ItemName, Quantity);
   }
```

---

I have modified my code based on the above suggestions. But now I am getting another error. The new error is: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

[image]

Comment: Post your testInsert function!

Comment: dereference the `Text` property.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing this

```
var ItemName = (Label)GridView2.SelectedRow.Cells[1].FindControl("lblItem");
```

`ItemName` would be a Label instead of the text value of `lblItem`. I would guess that both parameters of `rs.testInsert` method are string so you got the error because you're passing two Labels instead of two strings. You can get the text value from the `.Text` property of the label as below

```
var ItemName = ((Label)GridView2.SelectedRow.Cells[1].FindControl("lblItem")).Text;
var Quantity = ((Label)GridView2.SelectedRow.Cells[2].FindControl("lblQnty")).Text;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are finding Label control and assigning to var ItemName and var Quantity.So You are getting error "cannot convert from 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label' to 'string'".

```
 var ItemName = (Label)GridView2.SelectedRow.Cells[1].FindControl("lblItem");
 var Quantity = (Label)GridView2.SelectedRow.Cells[2].FindControl("lblQnty");
```

So, Add Text property to label.

```
 var ItemName = ((Label)GridView2.SelectedRow.Cells[1].FindControl("lblItem")).Text;
 var Quantity = ((Label)GridView2.SelectedRow.Cells[2].FindControl("lblQnty")).Text;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var ItemName = (Label)GridView2.SelectedRow.Cells[1].FindControl("lblItem");
```

here you will get the label control on the ItemName and you can get the label text value on string variable as given below.

```
string Text_Value= ItemName.text;
```